# How to create a new theme in Vaadin over an existing one?

Tags: css, sass, themes, vaadin

My client is using Vaadin to develop web applications and wants me to make a new theme for a project, based on the existing Valo theme in Vaadin 7.3. 
I know HTML and CSS (SCSS) and a little bit of jQuery but that's all, I'm a web designer with very limited, if any, programming skills. I'm trying to understand how Vaadin works and how to create new themes but I'm a bit lost on how to start. I've tried to read a 'book of vaadin' and other resources on the internet but I'm having a hard time because I don't know Java and most of it is written for programmers, not designers.

Can anyone explain me the principle of theming in Vaadin?
What can I change and what is contolled by Java?
Will my CSS be overwritten by Java and how? Where can I change/disable such behavior?
Where do I find a list of css rules/classes available in vaadin?
Do you know any Vaadin resources for designers?

Answer (score 0):

With vaadin you don't need to know java for creating/modifying themes.
Vaadin 7 uses SASS to simplify CSS management.
It requires you to understand sass, there are many tutorials available in the internet, for example [this one](http://sass-lang.com/guide).

The starting point is for sure [this link](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/themes.valo.html) in the book of vaadin and the [web page for the valo theme](https://vaadin.com/valo) itself.
On the [demo page](http://demo.vaadin.com/valo-theme/) you see what components are available/styled in valo.

If you wish to see what valo has for styles in css terms, look inside the vaadin-themes-7.3.5.jar file.
In the folder VAADIN\themes\valo\components you will see a scss file per component. And there you can also see the variables you can use for sass compilation.

The step to generate CSS file(s) from your scss definitions is usually automated in the build steps of vaadin.

Answer (score 0):

The beauty of valo is that is a theme highly customizable just by playing with the theme variables.
This means you can change how it looks with few easy modification in

**WEBCONTENT\VAADIN\themes*appname**appname*.scss**

In this same file you can, of course, add your own totally independent styles.
Component are set to use their "valo styles" by default. For each component you can then decide to add or remove some. There are already some built-in customization for the components in the **ValoTheme** class like **ValoTheme.BUTTON_DANGER** will render the normal Valo button but with the color set in the variable **$v-error-indicator-color**.

In the same folder **styles.scss** should be used to import the eventual sub-scss you might need. This is used to prefix your app-styles with [*appname-*] so they do not conflict with other style names.

**styles.css** is the actual css file the app will use, you have to "*Compile theme*" to update it

Leave alone addons.scss since is for internal framework use.

Good starting point are

https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/themes.valo.html chapter

https://vaadin.com/valo

https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Valo+Examples (some Valo prepared customizations, you'll see how with few adjustment the whole app changes a lot; you can see them in the Valo example and even in the Vaadin Sampler)

Good styling! Regards